# npm not working properly on windows 10

Tags: node.js, npm, windows-10, nvm

I have node.js installed via nvm, i have several versions and for some reason npm doesn't work on any of them. The versions are `4.5.0`, `5.8.0` and `6.5.0` with their corresponding npm versions which i can't get because when i type `npm -v`

```
$ npm -v
[TypeError: Cannot read property 'readFileSync' of undefined]
```

And if i try to npm install on any project i get something similar to this (varies a little bit from project to project)

```
$ npm install
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10586
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! node v4.5.0
npm ERR! npm  vTypeError: Cannot read property 'readFileSync' of undefined

npm ERR! Invalid Version: TypeError: Cannot read property 'readFileSync' of undefined
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
|
npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\repos\bakeIn\npm-debug.log
```

I've tried uninstalling nvm and reinstalling it, also removing it completely and then getting a fresh install of node and npm (not via nvm) from their website, but i get the same result. I rebooted my machine just in case but no luck.

I haven't been able to find something helpful on google or here, or maybe I'm missing something.

In any case its like the fs module is not available to npm when it runs, it was working correctly a couple of days ago.

Thanks in advance for any help :)

Comment: I don't know that Windows 10 is the problem.  I'm running Win 10 Pro 64 bit, I get 2.7.4 with npm -v... I built this machine about 3 months ago now, and haven't seen any issues.  Or if Win 10 is the problem, it's not a universal problem, which will make it difficult to troubleshoot.  You might need to submit a bug report.

Comment: @Aaron I agree, i just checked on my laptop (win 10 also) and it works as expected, and even on this pc it was working fine. Seems like a weird bug related to my overall environment, but it renders this machine useless to work with node :S, if nobody answers i'll submit a bug report, thanks for your comment.

Comment: Same problem with Windows 7

Comment: @AlessandroC Try running every antimalware, antivirus, etc that you can, it fixed in my case

Comment: I solved in another way: I had Dynatrace installed, this program corrupted the normal npm working; after unistalled Dynatrace, the error was solved.

Comment: @AlessandroC now that you say that, i think on that time i had dynatrace installed too and i removed it later, not sure of the timing. In anycase add it as an answer, it might help somebody else

Comment: interesting... so it can be a compatibility issue.

Comment: @AlessandroC yah, it was long ago, so i can't be sure if in my case it was related, but i do remember having dynatrace for a while, so its possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this particular case, doing a full scan for rootkits, spywares, virus, etc with different software's and cleaning what was found solved the issue. Not sure specifically what caused it but it was due to a program of that nature.